# Upload Comments to File Metadata "Get Info" Mac Command Line

Tags: macos, command-line, metadata

I'm working on a project that involves reading and writing metadata from files. On a mac, by right clicking and selecting 'Get Info' on a file, you can view and edit certain bits of metadata.

I have found a way to upload tags (extremely useful tool found [here](https://github.com/jdberry/tag)). Now I need a way to change a file's "Comments" from the command line.

Is there any way to do that?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would use the global variable `NSMetadataItemCommentKey` of `NSMetadataItem`:

**Swift**:

```
let NSMetadataItemCommentKey: String
```

**Objective-C**:

```
NSString *const NSMetadataItemCommentKey;
```

↳ [Foundation : NSMetadataItemCommentKey](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmetadataitemcommentkey)

Another ( *quick* ) way this might be done could be by calling `Applescript` from `bash`:

**update_comment.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

filepth="$1"
updated="$2"
comment=$(mdls -r -nullMarker "" -n kMDItemFinderComment "$filepth")

printf "%s ( comment ): %s\n" "${filepth##*/}" "$comment"
printf "%s ( updated ): " "${filepth##*/}" 

/usr/bin/osascript -e "set filepath to POSIX file \"$filepth\"" \
-e "set the_File to filepath as alias" \
-e "tell application \"Finder\" to set the comment of the_File to \"$updated\""
```

**synopsis**:

```
$ sh update_comment.sh /path/to/file "I'm the NEW comment"
```

**Result**:

```
file ( comment ): I'm a comment
file ( updated ): I'm the NEW comment
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I am a bit of a newbie with either of Swift or Objective C --  how can I run, say, the Swift command on a file on my desktop. Say the filename is "test.png" and the string I want to add to 'Comments' is "This is a test"? Thank you again very much.

Comment: You would normally create an application to do that. How are you currently updating the file tags ( is it a command-line application )? If so and you are comfortable doing it that way then it's simple to use something like an AppleScript ( see my edit ) from the command-line without knowing Swift or Objective-C.

Comment: That worked! Excellent, thank you very much. Now I have a little bit of a better idea of how this stuff works.

Comment: I may make a new post about this, but if you might know anything about this I would greatly appreciate it. The next thing I need to do, which may be a little trickier, is upload an image to the file. See an example of [what I need to do](http://imgur.com/a/aJ4w9). Thanks in advance again.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your immediate issue — it's the best way to say Thanks :)

Comment: I tried to do the same thing using `xattr`. I managed to set `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment`, saw the change being picked up by Spotlight via `mdls`, but Finder ignored the change. Going through AppleScript worked. Anyone would like to explain me why? Or point me somewhere I can learn more about extended attributes and how the interact with Finder and Spotlight and the CLI utils?