# Is there a way to write metadata to a file in R?

Tags: r, metadata

In particular, I would like to write to the "More Info" or "Comments" field found when you inspect a file's "Get Info" on MacOSX. I would then be able to access this metadata in R.

After a quick search, this is potentially possible in Python using the package [osxmetadata](https://pypi.org/project/osxmetadata/). Is there an R equivalent?

### Update

Contents of an `update_comment.sh` script I'm trying to use:

```bash
filepth="$1"
updated="$2"
/usr/bin/osascript -e "set filepath to POSIX file \"$filepth\"" -e "set the_File to filepath as alias" -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set the comment of the_File to \"$updated\""
```

Calling the shell file in R:

```r
system("sh update_comment.sh test.rds 'Changing the comment to this'")
```

From the command line, I can do this at once with:

```bash
/usr/bin/osascript -e "set filepath to POSIX file \"test.rds\"" -e "set the_File to filepath as alias" -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set the comment of the_File to \"Changing the comment to this\""
```

Ideally I don't want any dependency on an external file. Is there a way to do this without calling the shell script? I believe the main issue arises because of `system` only accepting the command as a character string.

### Solved

After experimenting with different combinations of escape characters, this command can now be run directly in `system` as a character string.

```r
system("/usr/bin/osascript -e 'set filepath to POSIX file \"test.rds\"' -e 'set the_File to filepath as alias' -e 'tell application \"Finder\" to set the comment of the_File to \"Changing the comment to this\"'")
```

The arguments for filepath and comment and *need* to be in wrapped in "" as far as I'm aware.

As a function:

```r
add_comment <- function(file, comment){
  system(paste0("/usr/bin/osascript -e 'set filepath to POSIX file \"", file, "\"' -e 'set the_File to filepath as alias' -e 'tell application \"Finder\" to set the comment of the_File to \"", comment, "\"'"),
         ignore.stdout = T, ignore.stderr = T)
}
```

Comment: https://rud.is/b/2021/04/13/quick-hit-processing-macos-application-metadata-weirdly-fast-with-mdls-and-r/ seems to implement this; a key not mentioned there and not guaranteed to be present is `kMDItemFinderComment`, so your function would need to interpret its absence as "no comment".

Comment: Okay great, I am now able to see all of the metadata. Do you know how I would update the `kMDItemFinderComment` (assuming for now it exists)?
For instance, how some ideal pseudocode would work (but sadly does not):
`mdls("data.RDS") <- mdls("data.RDS") %>%
  mutate(kMDItemFinderComment = "Changing comment to this")`

Comment: @r2evans How would I now go about *writing* this new data? ^

Comment: oh, I initially looked at how to access it ... errr, I don't know, does the `mdls` macos command line utility give the ability to change metadata values?

Comment: @r2evans I have a bit of a janky update using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42890648/22478665), creating an update_comment.sh file and running it from R using `system("sh update_comment.sh test.rds 'Changing the comment to this'")`.
It's far from ideal, but it works. I also came across [xattr](https://tinyapps.org/blog/201011300700_os_x_edit_metadata.html) and [osascript](https://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html), but the commands did not work for me. If you have any ideas on how to change the comments using the command line and `system`, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Share your shell script please

Comment: Sorry, finding it difficult to share code with multiple lines in a comment. New lines delimited with a ";"

`filepth="$1"; updated="$2"; /usr/bin/osascript -e "set filepath to POSIX file \"$filepth\"" -e "set the_File to filepath as alias" -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set the comment of the_File to \"$updated\""`

Comment: Sorry, I was actually thinking you'd [edit] your question and put it there in a [code block] (I just suggested an edit with that) ... comments are horrible for more than single-line expressions or data. But I think I get the point. You say both "but it works" and then "did not work", which one? If the latter, does it fail or just not result in a change? Any messages/warnings/errors (either in R or in the shell environment)? Have you tried running it outside of R to see if it is any more descriptive?

Comment: @r2evans Ah sorry, I'm still new to this haha. I figured it out and added a solved section. Thank you for your continued help and patience. I appreciate it!

Comment: I'm glad you found a hack. You may need to guard against embedded quotes in the comments you are trying to set. R's `system` and `system2` are bad when dealing with quotes, as they just concatenate everything together, and if there's anything not perfectly escaped/quoted, the target command/script will not get the expected arguments. If you know you'll never have `'` or `"` in your comments, then you should be safe enough with what you have. Glad you got it working!

Comment: @r2evans Yes great point. I will ban all punctuation for comments ;)